# How do I set up Craft 3 to web server in WAMP?

Tags: craft3, assets, database

I'm very new to Craft CMS, and I certainly love this concept! However, I keep trying to run it locally onto my computer following the documentation here https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html and can never figure out where to go from "Step 5: Set up the web server" for WAMP. Do I need to install Craft into the 'www' folder for WAMP? It's a very bland explanation for this section and cannot for the life of me figure this out! If anyone can assist please let me know as it is most likely something I have missed :( let me know any information that you need to help answer this question.

Comment: I see, and how would I point to the `web` folder? As I am unsure how to apply this. It mainly will appear with 'This site cannot be reached, the server IP address cannot be found.' This is probably because I don't know how to apply this :( but what you're suggesting will definitely help! If someone has worked on WAMP please let me know :)

Comment: Then it's a WAMP Problem. I use MAMP Pro which has a GUI for creating local urls an drag n' drop pointing into a directory. I guess you should check out on how to add virtual hosts in WAMP.

Comment: seems like Craft CMS would be much simpler through MAMP. Might have to buy a Mac then as makes life easier with coding, WAMP virtual hosts I attempted but still unsuccessful. Nothing's very self explanatory. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: @JonathanMackay MAMP is available on Windows: https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

I only know mamp. You have to point the local domain to the `web` folder. If you don't change the folder structure the composer libraries will live outside the public folder just fine.

Do you get any errors or something?